# Snowflake concatenation of strings

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a date where I need it in this final format. How can I contents that.

Column_date = 2023-01-01
format_date = “‘2023-01-01’::DATE”

How can I format like this . Tried pipe but got errors.

If you have a solution in exc cal is also fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snowflake TO_DATE() function.
Try this.

SELECT TO_DATE('2023-01-01');
OR
SELECT TO_DATE('2023-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');

Read more at , https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date

Comment: I am not looking to convert it to date. I need to format the date and create a another column as mentioned “final-columns”

Comment: You can try this. SELECT CONCAT('2023-01-01','::','DATE');